# phpMyAdmin "More Settings" Option Generates Blank Page

Tags: 13.04, php, phpmyadmin

**phpMyAdmin** works well except for a couple of links on the Home Page.

There are two links to **`More Settings`**, however they both take me to a *blank page*.

Am I missing a module, or does it need reinstalling?

The apache error.log reports:

```
[Fri May 31 09:22:06 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri May 31 09:23:04 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 31 11:14:32 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri May 31 11:15:52 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Thanks

Comment: check your apache error log for hints (`/var/log/apache/error.log`)

Comment: How did you install phpMyAdmin? Using the Ubuntu packages or in some other way? I have seen issues with phpMyAdmin "from source" generating a lot of Suhosin (security hardening for Apache) errors preventing pages to be displayed.

Comment: I installed it with `sudo apt-get install myphp5` there were a few minor password issues at the beginning but they got sorted out.

Comment: @Nanne sorry, looking at the wrong file. Adding Error log details to the question

Comment: The error log you provided shows a graceful shutdown of the Apache server - nothing is unusual about this. What do your regular *access* logs say on the failing requests?

Comment: Are you sure about that package? I can't seem to locate that on my system?

Comment: My error, I downloaded it and installed it from a package from the mySQL website

Comment: Re: similar or same bug??? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1175142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1175142) which has fix but not available in raring, at least not yet. *Why on earth is phpmyadmin using eval?*

> This bug was fixed in the package phpmyadmin - 4:4.0.1-2
>
> --------------- phpmyadmin (4:4.0.1-2) unstable; urgency=low
>
> - Add `/usr/share/javascript` to `open_basedir` config (closes: #708611).
> - Wrap check_file_access() function in config.inc.php in a
>     function_exists block, because this file sometimes gets included
>     twice (LP: #1175142).

### The Fixes

#### 1. Function already defined fix

Open problematic config file: `sudo vi /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and change the following:

```
function check_file_access($path)
{
    if (is_readable($path)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        error_log(
            'phpmyadmin: Failed to load ' . $path
            . ' Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.'
        );
        return false;
    }
}
```

to

```
if (!function_exists('check_file_access')) {
    function check_file_access($path)
    {
        if (is_readable($path)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            error_log(
                'phpmyadmin: Failed to load ' . $path
                . ' Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions.'
            );
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: All you're doing here is adding the function exists check `if (!function_exists('check_file_access')) { }`.

[Saucy proposed source with the fix](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/phpmyadmin/saucy-proposed/view/head:/debian/conf/config.inc.php)

#### 2. If that doesn't solve the problem, you may also need to add `/usr/share/javascript` to `open_basedir` config

Open the apache config file: `sudo vi /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` and change:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/
```

to

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/
```

[Saucy proposed source with the fix](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/phpmyadmin/saucy-proposed/view/head:/debian/conf/apache.conf)

Comment: Thanks for that, it was the first part that fixed it. So much more usable :D

Answer (score 1):

You could uninstall PHPMyAdmin and reinstall it. This might fix it. I would suggest deleting the phpmyadmin configuration databases in the SQL server and let it reconfigure the whole thing again. This should fix the issue.

```
sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin  
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: This would have worked, but I got couldn't wait for an answer so I deleted the whole lot and started from scratch... I now have worse problems, but I think I can sort them out!

Comment: An easier way to reinstall a package is just to use `install` with the `--reinstall` flag: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install phpmyadmin` If you want to delete global configuration files, use `purge` instead of `remove`, or use the `--purge` flag. So, to uninstall, delete global configuration files, and reinstall in one command, use: `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install phpmyadmin`